# Configure VSCode to ask to save modified files on exit

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to configure VS code to work the same as pretty much every editor I've ever used which is to save only when I tell it to and to ask to save modified files if I try to quit.

I've set Auto Save to "off"

I've set Hot Exit to "off"

As it is if I have modified files and I choose quit it just exits immediately, losing all my changes. I could have sworn this used to work.

version 1.41.1

Answer (score 3):

At least, VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020) mitigates that situation with:

[Prevent accidental close](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/v1_51.md#prevent-accidental-close)

> A new setting **`window.confirmBeforeClose`** was added to show a confirmation dialog before closing or leaving the workbench.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> - **`keyboardOnly`**: The confirmation will only be shown when you use a keybinding to close (for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>). (default)
> - **`always`**: The confirmation dialog will always be shown, even if you close from a mouse gesture.
> - **`never`**: The confirmation will never be shown.
>
> [image: Close confirmation dialog -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/images/1_51/web-confirmation.png]

But, that was only for Web.

VSCode 1.66 (Apr. 2022) will propose the same for the desktop app.
See [issue 14710](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14710) and [PR 147242](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147242)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was if you're in extension develop mode it just exits. If I pass in `--extensionDevelopmentPath some/path` then the save options are ignored. Without that it works as it's supposed to.

Apparently that's by design

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71405