# How can I VSCode to pop a notification "File not saved" when I turn it off?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The thing is:

1. I made a modification on a file.
2. I didn't save it.
3. I didn't close the editor; I close VSCode directly, and it didn't ask me about the unsaved file.
4. I deleted the file permanently, not in the bin.
5. When I open VSCode, it restores the deleted file.

How could I turn off this function? I mean how to set it to pop a notification when I close it without saving, like other software, rather than restore the file when I reopen the VSCode even if I have deleted the file permanently.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522389/configure-vscode-to-ask-to-save-modified-files-on-exit, the `Files: Hot Exit` : `off` setting should work for you.

Comment: @Mark Tried that. it works well. thanks.